# What is Contents.json required for in iOS development?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is the Contents.json file (autogenerated by Xcode) needed at all for developing iOS apps. Can we delete it without any consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used as part of the [Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) and cannot be removed if you are using the Asset Catalog for app icons, etc.